# Typescript: instantiate a generic class with the type parameter value in a variable

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

In TypeScript how do you create an instance of a generic class?
(1) When the type parameter value is known at compile time, and
(2) when name of the type to use as the type parameter is passed as the value of a string?

https://jsfiddle.net/zn71am4v/

```
interface ITheValue {
  TheValue: string;
}

class Foo implements ITheValue {
  TheValue: string;

  constructor(val: string) {
    this.TheValue = val
  }
}

class Bar implements ITheValue {
  TheValue: string;
  constructor(val: string) {
    this.TheValue = val
  }
}

class Buz<T implements ITheValue> {
  Thing: T
  
  constructor(val: string) {
    this.T = new T(val);
  }
    
  getTheValue(): string {
    return this.Thing.TheValue;
  }
}

function run(whichOne: string, theValue: string): string {
  var f: Foo = new Foo('foo value'); // Well at least this works.
  
  // Can this be made to work? (It can in a proper language like C# :p)
  var buz = new Buz<whichOne>(theValue);

  // Even this doesn't work.
  var buz = new Buz<Foo>(theValue);

  return `The value is: ${buz.getTheValue}.`;
}

document.querySelector("#app").innerHTML = run('Foo', 'the value');
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, get a proper editor like https://www.typescriptlang.org/play and fix your Buz

```
class Buz<T extends ITheValue> {
  //        ^ not implements
  Thing: T
  
  constructor(val: string) {
    this.Thing = new T(val);
    //               ^! 'T' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.(2693)
  }
    
  getTheValue(): string {
    return this.Thing.TheValue;
  }
}


// This DOES work, you just got a "duplicate buz variable definition" error
var buz1 = new Buz<Foo>(theValue);
```

So, the error is that you don't pass the *T constructor* and it doesn't know where to take it

```
class But<T extends ITheValue> {
  Thing: T
  constructor(TMaker: new (val: string) => T, val: string) {
    this.Thing = new TMaker(val);
  }
}

new But(Foo, 'test')
```

will work fine

Comment: What is this mysterious expression? `TMaker: new (val: string) => T, val: string`. I cannot parse it.

Comment: TMaker is a new-able function that returns T?